# Skel import in Meteor Project

Tags: javascript, meteor, skel

I'm new working with Meteor, I'm trying to import a javascript file: skel.min.js, skel-layout.min.js and skel-viewport.min.js into a project.

The 3 files are on the client/js path (`client/js/skel.min.js`, `client/js/skel-layout.min.js` and `client/js/skel-viewport.min.js`).

I have the base layout in "client/baseLayout/baseLayout.js" and I deliver as follows:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import * as skel from '../js/skel.min.js';


(function ($) {
    skel.breakpoints ({
        xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
        large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
        medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
        small: '(max-width: 736px)',
        xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)',
        'xlarge-to-max': '(min-width: 1681px)',
        'small-to-xlarge': '(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1680px)'
    });
.
.
.
```

But it always shows me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: skel is not defined
    at skel-layout.min.js (app.js? hash = e2c356f13dbdbc8f5ea02b405b7c429aff6b8bef: 699)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js? hash = 8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62: 343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js? hash = 8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62: 238)
    at app.js? hash = e2c356f13dbdbc8f5ea02b405b7c429aff6b8bef: 1157
```

I tried to move the files but it does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

My packages:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.2.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.5   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.1.2    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.8.3              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.4            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
iron:router
twbs:bootstrap
rlespagnol:skeleton-css
johnantoni:meteor-skeleton
jquery
fourseven:scss
```

to thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue isn't your code that you posted, but when Meteor eagerly loads files it does two things.

1. It loads them alphabetically, so `skel-layout` is running before `skel.min` which is the error in your console. `skel.min` needs to run first.
2. It wraps them in a new closure, so they don't pollute the global namespace.

In addition to that, because `skel.min` uses the UMD pattern and Meteor uses common.js, it registers itself with the module loader so it can be called with `require()`, instead of loading itself onto the window global.

Looking at the code in the `skel` repo, `skel-layout` and `skel-viewport` doesn't use UMD or attempt to `require()` or `import` skel, it just expects it to be available in the current scope.

In other words. Skel have half-arsed their module pattern.

Thankfully there's a quick fix.
Put all three files in the `client/compatibility` folder and prefix the names with the load order:

```
1-skel.min.js
2-skel-layout.min.js
3-skel-viewport.min.js
```

For files in the `compatibility` folder, Meteor doesn't load them in a new closure and so they can freely pollute the global scope.